# In flutter, integer values from firebase are put into a double list and averaged

Tags: flutter, dart

In the application I made in Flutter, information on how many pages a student read per day comes from firebase, and in the application, it assigns them to a double list and then takes the weekly average. But something goes wrong while adding it to the list.

```
List<ModelData> students = [];

for (var student in students) {
FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('students_data')
            .where('mail', isEqualTo: student.userID)
            .where(
              'date',
              isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startDate,
            )
            .where('date', isLessThanOrEqualTo: finishDate)
            .get()
            .then((value2) {
          try {
            for (var i = 0; i < value2.docs.length; i++) {
              data.add(
                ModelData(
                  date: value2.docs[i]['date'] ?? "",
                  readingbookvalue: value2.docs[i]['readingbookvalue'] ?? "",
                  mail: value2.docs[i]['mail'] ?? "",
                ),
              );

              if (data[i].readingbookvalue == "") {
                double value = 0;
                setState(() {
                  student.readingbooks?.add(value);
                });
              } else {
                double value = double.parse(data[i].readingbookvalue ?? "0");
                setState(() {
                 student.readingbook?.add(value);
                });
              }

            student.readingbook_average =
                student.readingbook!.reduce((a, b) => a + b) /
                    student.readingbook!.length;
          } catch (e) {
            e.toString();
          }
        }).whenComplete(() {
          setState(() {
            loading = false;
          });
        });
}

class ModelData{
  String? date;
  String? readingbookvalue;
  int? mail;
  double? readingbook;
  List<double>? readingbook_average;

  ModelOgrenci({
    this.readingbook,
    this.readingbook_average,
  });


}
```

Comment: "something goes wrong" can you please share what goes wrong?

Comment: It doesn't add to List but I gave Lists a null value and it worked: = []